# SYSAUX used space close to 100%

Tags: oracle-11g, system-tables

I am using Oracle 11g database server.

I checked the `SYSAUX` used space using Object Browser, and it shows 99%.

What will happen if it reaches 100%?

Answer (score 1):

That depends-- are your data files set to autoextend?  If they are, they'll just grow themselves up to whatever limit you may have set (or to the size of the available disk).  If not, whenever the database tries to allocate the next extent in the tablespace, the operation will fail and whatever is trying to write data to a table in the `SYSAUX` tablespace will fail.  There are many products that you might install in `SYSAUX` and any one of them might be the unlucky one that needs to allocate the next extent so you can't really predict what impact that would have.  I'd guess that you'd stop being able to write audit information since the audit trail is commonly in `SYSAUX` and commonly the most prevalent user of space among products that are commonly installed in `SYSAUX`.

You can check whether your data files are set to autoextend by looking at the `autoextensible` attribute in `dba_data_files`.

```
select file_name, autoextensible
  from dba_data_files
 where tablespace_name = 'SYSAUX';
```

Comment: Mr. Justin Cave.Thank you very much to your reply.And my situation of auto extend may be 'no'. Therefore, we need extend it as soon as possible right?

Comment: @user77642 - That or free up some space most likely.  You'd know, presumably, if a large amount of the "used space" was allocated by not used because, for example, you purged a lot of data from the audit trail recently.

Comment: I got a result by following command 
select file_name, autoextensible
  from dba_data_files
 where tablespace_name = 'SYSAUX';
And it says `YES`.
Therefore I can make sure autoextend should be enabled.

But about the `SYSTEM` it also will be happened the same things as `SYSAUX` when used(`SYSTEM`) was reached 100%?

Sorry too many times.
But thanks in advance.

Comment: `SYSTEM` being full is worse than `SYSAUX` being full, but both situations are "bad".

Answer (score 1):

I've been in this situation before when SYSAUX was full and there was no loss of functionality at all.

The only problem I experienced is that AWR data could not be collected whilst the tablespace was full.

There may be other problems but I never saw them personally.